# How can I use the status of a job submitted remotely to a cluster, which uses Loadleveler, as a loop control parameter inside a BASH script?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, batch-processing, jobs, job-scheduling

The cluster uses Loadleveler to schedule jobs. I wish for the loop to start its next iteration only when a job submitted in its current iteration is completed.
I understand that `wait` can be used to do this but I can't figure how. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3
do

    submit job 

    retrieve job id

    check if the submitted job is over so the next iteration of for can start

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is small piece of code that could help you.

```
#!/bin/bash

total_attempts=0

for attempt in 1 2 3;
do
  echo attempt $attempt      #Use your submit job here

  # initialise stuff 
  counter=0                  #Use your retrieve_job_id here

  # since the next step is to check, we first need to retrieve state.
  rand=$((RANDOM))           #Use your get_job_state here

  # Check we didn't reach completion
  while [ $rand -gt 2000 ];  #Use your criterium here
  do  
    # You probably want to change the following lines...
    echo $rand;              #You don't want this line, but it'll help you understand what's going on
    # get new state
    rand=$((RANDOM));        #Use your get_job_state here
    counter=$((counter+1))
  done

  #At this line, the criterium has been met for the attempt.       
  echo attempt $attempt got $rand ! #You don't want this line, but it'll help you understand what's going on

  # A job has been completed, so maybe we need to clean stuff up.
  total_attempts=$((total_attempts+counter)) #Use your imagination here :)
done

echo $total_attempts attempts required to finish 3 jobs.
```